# как подружить split с кириллицей? Java

Tags: java, split

Нужно разбить строку на отдельные слова. Сделал так. Отрабатывает хорошо с текстом, написанным латиницей. Но вот слова, написанные кириллицей не распознает. Подскажите, что можно сделать?

public class TextSplitter {

```
public ArrayList<String> splitTextToWords(String string){
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String[]strings = string.split("\\W");

    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++){
        if(strings[i].length()>0){
            list.add(strings[i].toLowerCase());
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать так добавить кириллицу

```
String[] strings = string.split("[^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9_]");
```

либо делить по пробелам

```
String[] strings = string.split("\\s");
```

но первый по мне лучше. Потому что второй делит по пробелам.

Comment: Aziz спасибо! Первый способ мне как раз отлично подходит!